# Determing the structure of the subgroup of an automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose we have two automorphisms of an extension field $L=\mathbb{Q}(t)$ for some variable, given by $\sigma: t \mapsto 1-t$ and $\tau : t \mapsto \frac{1}{t}$. Clearly $\langle \sigma , \tau \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(L)$, but how can we find the abstract structure of this group (i.e. by considering the relations). Also, can we determine the subfields corresponding to $\langle \sigma \rangle$ and $ \langle \tau \rangle$?

**EDIT**

So the question got voted down for some reason (my first ever vote down so if someone could relay why that happened I'd be grateful).

Some thoughts are that:

$\sigma \tau (t) = \frac{t-1}{t}$ and $-\tau \sigma (t) = \frac{t-1}{t}$ and so the elements satisfy $\sigma \tau = - \tau \sigma$, which gives us some information about this group. [It has been pointed out that this calculation is essentially meaningless]

Also, $\sigma ^ 2 = \tau ^2 = \text{id}$

**ANOTHER (BETTER) EDIT**

I've spotted now that $(\sigma \tau )^3 = \text{id}$ so I can make the following claim

> > $$\langle \sigma , \tau \rangle \cong S_3$$

Comment: Please tell us your thoughts so far :)

Comment: I have added some thoughts

Comment: «$-\tau\sigma$» does not mean anything, really (because the group is not abelian). Have you computed $\tau^2$?

Comment: I've done some more work, is it correct?

Comment: In particular, can someone help me with the subfields corresponding to the subgroups.

Comment: Since $\sigma$ has order 2, both $t + \sigma(t)$ and $t\sigma(t)$ are fixed by $\sigma$. Now $t+\sigma(t)=1$, which is not very useful, but $t\sigma(t)=t(1-t)$. Show that $|{\mathbb Q}(t):{\mathbb Q}(t(1-t))|=2$ and deduce that ${\rm Fix}(\langle \sigma \rangle) = {\mathbb Q}(t(1-t))$. Do something similar for $\tau$.

Comment: Surely $t(1-t)$ is an element in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ since it is a field and therefore since it contains $1$ and $t$, it contains $1-t$ and also $t(1-t)$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Of course $t(1-t)$ is an element of ${\mathbb Q}(t)$. You were asked to identify a subfield of ${\mathbb Q}(t)$.

Comment: Yes, of course. My mistake. I just can't see how to find an irreducible polynomial for $t(1-t)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$

Comment: You have it the wrong way round. You are trying to prove that $|{\mathbb Q}(t):{\mathbb Q}(u)|=2$ with $u=t(1-t)$, so you have to find the minimal polynomial for $t$ over ${\mathbb Q}(u)$.